# Why is my async callback running in the same thread?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, asynchronous

I'm trying to use the `FtpWebRequest` async calls (`BeginGetResponse` / `EndGetResponse`).

However, it appears that the callback from `BeginGetResponse` is running in the same thread as my application, when I was under the impression it would use a different (and thread pool) thread. This means my application blocks inside the callback before continuing.

I've setup a LINQPad proof-of-concept as follows:

```
"Starting".Dump();
Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode().Dump(); 
Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread.Dump();

IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse((ar) => 
{
     "Inside Callback".Dump();
     Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode().Dump();
     Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread.Dump();
     var resp = request.EndGetResponse(ar);
     "Callback Complete".Dump();
}, null);

"After Callback".Dump();
```

This prints output as follows:

```
Starting
33
False
Inside Callback
33
False
Callback Complete
After Callback
```

What I would expect is something like this (assuming the callback took long enough to run):

```
Starting
33
False
Inside Callback
44
True
After Callback // App continues despite callback running
Callback Complete
```

With the callback running on the same application thread it means if something inside the callback takes a long time (e.g. introducing a `Thread.Sleep` for argument's sake), my application blocks there. This means I cannot setup a timeout on the request (e.g. with a `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject`).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What you're missing is that the callback is called only *after* the request has completed. The point of the asynchronous request is to ensure that the request itself does not block your thread.

Comment: Right, but if the request was asynchronous, why is the callback not in an asynchronous thread pool thread? Assume the request took a long time (and was async), and the app thread had moved on, does that mean the callback could block the application thread at any point later? I'll see if I can setup a slow server and find out.

Comment: What's the value of `ar.CompletedSynchronously` in the callback? ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.completedsynchronously.aspx))

Comment: @dtb `ar.CompletedSynchronously` is `true`.

Comment: @JeffMercado So it seems. Care to post it @dtb?

Comment: also, mostly unrelated, but you shouldn't rely on `GetHashCode` for what you're doing; it's not guaranteed to be unique among threads. There's a `ManagedThreadId` for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an asynchronous operation can be completed immediately by the BeginXXX method, it doesn't run the callback on a thread-pool thread but sets the [IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.completedsynchronously.aspx) to `true` and executes the callback synchronously.

Comment: I also feel cautious enough to go check some of my other invocation code now (where I'm invoking an action with a thread kill timeout) to make sure it's not running in the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the BeginGetResponse method calls callback within context of caller thread

Comment: I assume as much as well, but this contradicts documentation I've seen, and kind of defeats the purpose of an async call when it's callback can block the app thread at any point in the future. I guess I need to nest a `BeginInvoke` in my callback.